# ASP.net simple repeater question

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to use the repeat without binding it to a datasource, is this possible?

```
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPageNav">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="pageLink" ID="pageLink">#</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Then in my code, I want to loop through adding the repeater item template for each link available.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < thisTemplate.specification.pagination; i++)
            {

            }
```

So the end results should be something like:

```
                <a class="pageLink" href="#">1</a>
                <a class="pageLink" href="#">2</a>
                <a class="pageLink" href="#">3</a>
                <a class="pageLink" href="#">4</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want only single simple link you don't need Repeater IMO you can have simple Panel then create the links on the fly:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
   link.CssClass = "pageLink";
   link.NavigateUrl = "#";
   link.Text = i.ToString();
   MyPanel.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

Comment: +1 Agree, if the OP wants to add links in a for-loop, indeed the repeater serves no purpose and your code is a lot easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of integers up to what you need and bind that to your repeater, using the value as the text for your hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to bind a Repeater to some kind of datasource. Try using an array of ints as @Paddy suggests.

Incidentally, you'll need to modify the markup within the `<ItemTemplate>` tags to get your hyperlinks to display one above the other as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN defines [`asp:Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as

> A data-bound list control that allows
>   custom layout by repeating a specified
>   template for each item displayed in
>   the list.

Which essentially means we have to bind it to a datasource. Why dont you try and implemt something like this

Markup

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPageNav">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="pageLink" runat="server" CssClass="pageLink" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Link") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code

```
public partial class Repeater : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<URL> urls = new List<URL>()
            {
                new URL(){ Link = "http://www.google.com", Title = "Google"},
                new URL(){ Link = "http://www.yahoo.com", Title = "Yahoo"}
            };
            rptPageNav.DataSource = urls;
            rptPageNav.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

public class URL
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```